# Good idea to keep persistent true in chrome extension manifest for timer feature?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to have a timer feature in my chrome extension where a timer starts and stop with the click of a button on extension.

The timer should run even when extension is not open. For this purpose, I want to use background script and keep it's "Persistent" property to "True" in manifest.

Do you think above approach is a good idea in terms of Chrome policy and not create any issue in chrome webstore upload?

Comment: There's no policy about type of the background script so use whatever you want. Personally I would use a [persistent-on-demand background script](/a/58577052).